# Problems with mixing Icelandic and German with LuaLaTex

Tags: pdftex, luatex, babel, letters

So what I am trying to do is to use the `letter-classic` class with LuaLaTeX (`This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (MiKTeX 2.9) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2015.11.10)  25 NOV 2015 09:30`) as included in MikTeX.

It bombs in `icelandic.ldf` with errors like these:

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.144 \DeclareTextCommand{\ooob}{T1}{\sob {
                                         ó}{.85}{0}{.04}{0}}
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.
Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.

! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.145 \DeclareTextCommand{\OOob}{T1}{\sob {
                                         Ó}{.7}{0}{0}{0}}
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.
Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.

! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.148 \DeclareTextCommand{\eeob}{T1}{\sob {
                                         é}{1}{0}{.04}{0}}
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.
Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.

! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.149 \DeclareTextCommand{\EEob}{T1}{\sob {
                                         É}{1}{0}{.04}{0}}
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.
Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.

! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.152 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"
                                   ó}{\ooob}
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.
Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.

! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
<argument> icelandic@sh@\string "@\string ï¿½
                                  \ooob @
l.153 \declare@shorthand
                      {icelandic}{"Ó}{\OOob}
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been (re)read.
Just continue, I'll change it to 0xFFFD.
```

My minimal working example is this one:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper]{letter-classic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[icelandic,german,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}
\newcommand{\ISL}[1]{\foreignlanguage{icelandic}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DEU}[1]{\foreignlanguage{german}{#1}}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % needed with pdfLaTeX, but not with LuaLaTeX (see comment below question)

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Troll family\\\ISL{Elliðaárdalur}\\\ISL{999 Reykjavík}\\ICELAND}
\fromname{\DEU{Mäxchen Mustermann}}
\fromstreet{\DEU{Musterstraße 123}}
\fromtown{12345 Musterstadt}
\fromphone{+49 123 4567890}
\fromtownshort{Musterstadt}
\fromsignature{\DEU{Mäxchen}}

\subject{\ISL{Jólasveinar}}
\opening{Folks,}

do you know the current address of the \ISL{Jólasveinar} and/or their parents \ISL{Grýla} and \ISL{Leppalúði}?

\closing{\ISL{Með kveðju,}}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

The actual document worked without problems until a few months ago, using pdfLaTeX (and still does, see below).

How it looks [image: when rendered with pdfLaTeX].

Can anyone explain to me how to mix Icelandic and German *using LuaLaTeX* with the `letter-classic` class?

---

I looked into the KOMA letter class already, but I prefer a slightly more modern/custom look for the letter head, such that at this moment I really want to avoid that one.

Comment: You *mustn't* use `inputenc` with LuaLaTeX. But, unfortunately, icelandic-babel is not compatible with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg: even when taking that line out, I get the same errors ... obviously pdfLaTeX now shows me the individual bytes of the UTF-8 codepoints I am using. But LuaLaTeX simply gives the same errors after commenting out that line.

Comment: Simple solution: Don't use `babel`. Take care of hyphenation by hand.

Comment: @Johannes_B: well `babel` appears to do something more than merely hyphenation. Without it I could not mix Icelandic and German characters in the same document *and* have them rendered correctly.

Comment: Of course you can: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
ä ß  Elliðaárdalur
\end{document}`

Comment: @Johannes_B: interesting, I could swear this used to be a problem within the past few years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not in mixing Icelandic and German. A smaller example shows the issue in *all* document classes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

Running this through LuaLaTeX produces the same error you see (and similar ones later on):

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.144 \DeclareTextCommand{\ooob}{T1}{\sob {
                                         ?}{.85}{0}{.04}{0}}
?
```

Unfortunately, the file `icelandic.ldf` loaded by `babel` hardcodes four Latin-1 characters to be used for shorthands in

```
"Ó "ó "É "é
```

and, when LuaTeX is reading the file, it chokes on that invalid input. XeTeX is more forgiving in this respect and doesn't choke.

As it stands, `babel-icelandic` is not compatible with LuaLaTeX and there's no workaround, as far as I can see, except writing a modified `icelandic.ldf` file.

Lines 142 to 157 should be

```
142 \DeclareTextCommand{\oob}{T1}{\sob {o}{.85}{0}{.04}{0}}
143 \DeclareTextCommand{\Oob}{T1}{\sob {O}{.7}{0}{0}{0}}
144 \DeclareTextCommand{\ooob}{T1}{\sob {^^f3}{.85}{0}{.04}{0}}
145 \DeclareTextCommand{\OOob}{T1}{\sob {^^d3}{.7}{0}{0}{0}}
146 \DeclareTextCommand{\eob}{T1}{\sob {e}{1}{0}{.04}{0}}
147 \DeclareTextCommand{\Eob}{T1}{\sob {E}{1}{0}{.04}{0}}
148 \DeclareTextCommand{\eeob}{T1}{\sob {^^e9}{1}{0}{.04}{0}}
149 \DeclareTextCommand{\EEob}{T1}{\sob {^^c9}{1}{0}{.04}{0}}
150 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"o}{\oob}
151 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"O}{\Oob}
152 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"^^f3}{\ooob}
153 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"^^d3}{\OOob}
154 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"e}{\eob}
155 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"E}{\Eob}
156 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"^^e9}{\eeob}
157 \declare@shorthand{icelandic}{"^^c9}{\EEob}
```

Changes are in the lines where `^^` appears; I added the line numbers for convenience.

A bug report should be filed to the maintainer of `babel`.

Comment: There's an address listed in http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel-icelandic/icelandic.pdf

Comment: email bounced. will try alternative route.

Comment: @0xC0000022L With today's update of `babel-icelandic` some of the problems have been solved, but others arose. `:-(` For instance you can't use it in LuaTeX without `fontspec`; and the characters with the ogonek are typeset wrongly.

Comment: @egreg Please, could you report a bug with a MWE?

Comment: @JavierBezos Hasn't this been solved with the recent update?

Comment: @egreg I don't know. This language is somewhat complex because Old Icelandic requires a few unusual characters (eg, o with acute and ogonek). The issues with the latin1 encoding should be solved, but support for lua/xe is new and therefore it might be still incomplete or buggy.

Comment: @JavierBezos I made a test and found that the old characters *need* `fontspec`, when XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is used; however, they are typeset very badly with Latin Modern, badly with Libertine and well with Old Standard (so it's font dependent). If one doesn't load `fontspec`, a fatal error happens. No problem with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it's font dependent. With Cambria works like a charm, too. But that's what happens when we delegate these things to the font, as essentially lua/xe do with fontspec. As to the error without `fontspec`, will have a look at it, but a minimal example would be veeery useful.

Comment: @JavierBezos `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}\begin{document}"é\end{document}`

Answer (score 7):

As a work-around you could switch locally to ansinew reading with luainputenc: (edited a bit to reset the catcodes afterwards and also removed the write call back so that the toc now contains again real utf8).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luatexbase} %not needed now, but probably in the future.
\PushCatcodeTableNumStack
\usepackage[ansinew]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\PopCatcodeTableNumStack

\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_input_buffer', 'luainputenc.fake_utf_read')
           luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_output_buffer','luainputenc.fake_utf_write')
           luainputenc.state = stopped}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{öäüß}
äöüß €
 ólasveinar Grýla Leppalúði
\end{document}
```

But it is quite possible that some other things in icelandic.ldf are not suitable to luatex and then you will have to adapt more.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Why not use `polyglossia`?  I don't have `letter-classic`, but here is similar version in `letter`:

[image: Sample]

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{icelandic,german}

\newcommand{\ISL}[1]{\texticelandic{#1}}
\newcommand{\DEU}[1]{\textgerman{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Troll family\\\ISL{Elliðaárdalur}\\\ISL{999 Reykjavík}\\ICELAND}
\name{\DEU{Mäxchen Mustermann}}
\address{\DEU{Musterstraße 123}\\
12345 Musterstadt}
\telephone{+49 123 4567890}
\signature{\DEU{Mäxchen}}

\opening{Folks,}

\begin{center}
  \ISL{Jólasveinar}
\end{center}

Do you know the current address of the \ISL{Jólasveinar} and/or their parents \ISL{Grýla} and \ISL{Leppalúði}?

\closing{\ISL{Með kveðju,}}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update.** This bug was fixed long ago, and `babel-icelandic` is compatible with `luatex` and `xetex`.